# ANDROID : Intent to fpdf in browser downloads php file instead of pdf generated

Tags: php, android, android-intent, pdf-generation, fpdf

Good day!

I have a function in my mobile application which in a click of a button makes an intent of :

```
                Intent I = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                I.setData(Uri.parse(URL));
                CONTEXT.startActivity(I);
```

With the `URL` as https://mydomain.xyz/outputs/grades/index.php?ID=1000

However it just downloads the index.php file itself rather than the generated pdf file using the fpdf library (from: http://www.fpdf.org/).

I tried opening the link directly from a browser and it downloaded the generated pdf file.

I am just a student creating an app for a school project so I am not that well versed in this things so I am very thankful for all the help :)

Comment: That domain does not resolve. What is the **actual** URL?

Comment: never mind his actual url, how about the code? Is PHP even enabled on Apache?

Comment: it looks like you have problems with your server. It likely does not support PHP, and treats them as regullar text files.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the correct HTTP headers for your request, specifically: `Content-Type` and `Content-Disposition`.

`Content-Type` will tell the server what content the client is expecting: `Content-Type: application/pdf` will let the server know that the expected content is of type `PDF`.

`Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.jpg"` to specify the response should be a download and not displayed in a browser or anything.